# how do I bypass frp without sim card on boost mobile zte prestige?

Tags: google

I need to bypass or find a way to make a zte prestige w/o sim card boost (mobile) into a wifi phone or a phone that can at the very least connect to wifi for internet. it will connect to wifi but it wont open anything so there's no way to get internet or get to a browser because of FRP Google Lock. Anyone know how I can use the internet at the very least and/or bypass the google frp or get internet browsing capabilities? Thank you, appreciate any help.